# spreading a DataGrid across the screen will all it's items visible

Tags: java, android, android-layout, datagrid

I'm writing my first android application. I'm using android 2.3.3 SDK.
the game is kind of a cards game that has a 4x4 grid of cards on the screen.

when the game starts the only thing visible on the screen is the datagrid (no menus or nothing).

so the GameActivity layout is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/faces_grid_view"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
</GridView>
```

this is the relevant code of the onCreate function of the GameActivity class:

```
          Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            final int width  = display.getWidth();
            final int height = display.getHeight();

            final int bottomPadding=150;
             //Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            gameTurns = new ArrayList<GameTurn>();
            imageWidth=width/4;
            imageHeight=(height-bottomPadding)/4;
            imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this,imageWidth,imageHeight);
            facesGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.faces_grid_view);
            facesGridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
```

in the onCreate() code I'm getting the defaultDisplaySize, divide it by 4 so i'll know the max height and width that an image can take.

- for some reason I need to add a bottomPadding. I checked it on galaxy note and galaxy tab 10.1 and maybe the getDefaultDisplay also returns the space of the bottom toolbar of the tablet itself so the pictures overlap the all screen without any padding.

as you can see I set an adapter for the GridView. the adapter extends BaseAdapter
and i paste to his constructor the width and height the I calculated earlier.

the getView function of the adapter contains the following:

```
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                LayoutParams param = new    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(this.imageWidth,this.imageHeight);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(param));
                imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                imageView.setPadding(1,1,1,1);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
```

so a couple of questions:

1. is there a way just to configure the datagrid to be visible on the all screen and to show all items with no scrolling without configuration the image width or height ? why do I need to work so hard for such a simple task?
2. if I do need to calculate stuff myself, is there a way to get the actual Activity height and width so I won't need to add any padding? welp I want it to work on all scree sizes in landscape and portrait.

I tired to change and play with the configuration for many days and that's the best I've achieved so far so any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

## update

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:weightSum="4" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
     >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/face"
    android:onClick="onItemClick"
     />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/face"
    android:onClick="onItemClick"
     />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/face"
    android:onClick="onItemClick"
     />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/face"
    android:onClick="onItemClick"
     />

</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
     >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/face"
    android:onClick="onItemClick"
     />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/face"
    android:onClick="onItemClick"
     />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/face"
    android:onClick="onItemClick"
     />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/face"
    android:onClick="onItemClick"
     />

</TableRow>
    <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/face"
    android:onClick="onItemClick"
     />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/face"
    android:onClick="onItemClick"
     />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/face"
    android:onClick="onItemClick"
     />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/face"
    android:onClick="onItemClick"
     />

</TableRow>
    <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView13"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/face"
    android:onClick="onItemClick"
     />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView14"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/face"
    android:onClick="onItemClick"
     />
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imageView15"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/face"
    android:onClick="onItemClick"
     />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView16"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/face"
    android:onClick="onItemClick"
     />

</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

this xml file results in a 4 images centered and spread vertically (this fits the all screen so there may be more below).

[image: screenshot]
.

what did i miss? :)

thanks!

Kfir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way just to configure the datagrid to be visible on the all
>   screen and to show all items with no scrolling without configuration
>   the image width or height ? why do I need to work so hard for such a
>   simple task?

This is a simple task just that you're using the wrong widget. You would generally use a `GridView` if the grid of cells is bigger than the screen so you could benefit from the `GridView`'s recycling mechanism(to improve performance and to don't get in trouble with the app's memory). This is not your case as you want all the cells to be visible.

I would use a `TableLayout` with width and height set to `FILL_PARENT`(with `stretchColumns` set to `*` so the row columns will have the same width) which will contain four `TableRows`(with `layout_weight` set to `1`(and `weighSum` set to `4` for the parent `TableLayout`) so they will have equal height), also the `layout_height` for the `TableRow` will be set to `0dp`. Each `TableRow` will contain four `ImageViews`.

> if I do need to calculate stuff myself, is there a way to get the
>   actual Activity height and width so I won't need to add any padding?
>   Help I want it to work on all scree sizes in landscape and portrait.

I would advise you to use the solution I posted above. If you still want to use the `GridView` then make it fill all the width/height (by using `fill_parent` and not `wrap_content` like you did for the `layout_width/height`) and in the `onCreate` method use a `Handler` to `post` a `Runnable` in which you retrieve the `GridView`'s  `LayoutParams` and use those to set up the adapter.

Comment: thanks. I still don't get the expected results. I posted here the new xml file. thanks so far :)

Comment: ohh.. i also added weightSum=4 to each tableRow and layout_weight=1 to each image. looks like it works now. testing.

Comment: @ufk I edited the answer a bit later realizing that I forgot the `weightSum` part. Glad I could help you.